# Get value of variable by it's name : Java

Tags: java, reflection

I would like to get a variable's value by having variable's name, how can I achieve it ?

```
private String firstName = "some xpath";
private String secondName = "some xpath";

public void findElement(String fName , String sName){ // fName = "firstName" , sName = "secondName"
driver.findElementByXPath(/*here goes reflection of fName*/);
driver.findElementByXPath(/*here goes reflection of sName*/);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: This sort of thing is more common in scripting languages than in a language like Java. You can achieve this through reflection, but it would probably not be exactly what you expect if you come from a scripting language. The question is why you would want to do this, as this seems to be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: if you print `System.out.println(fName);` , it will anyhow give you the value **firstName**

Comment: @NeerajJain - I want something more generic than println. as it was suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Reflection, you can do:

```
public void print(String fName , String sName) throws Exception {
    Field fNameField = this.getClass().getDeclaredField(fName);
    Field sNameField = this.getClass().getDeclaredField(sName);
    System.out.println(fNameField.get(this));
    System.out.println(sNameField.get(this));
}
```

Comment: You have to use different names for the local variables.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your private variables are in a different class say for eg:

```
public class PrivateObject {
    private String firstName = "myFName";    
    private String secondName = "mySName";
}
```

you can access them through reflections like this:

```
public void print(String fName , String sName){ // fName = "firstName" , sName = "secondName"
    PrivateObject p = new PrivateObject();
    try {
        Field fNameField = PrivateObject.class.getDeclaredField(fName);
        Field sNameField = PrivateObject.class.getDeclaredField(sName);
        fNameField.setAccessible(true);
        sNameField.setAccessible(true);
        String fNamefieldValue = (String) fNameField.get(p);
        String sNamefieldValue = (String) sNameField.get(p);
        System.out.println("fName = " + fNamefieldValue);
        System.out.println("sName = " + sNamefieldValue);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score -5):

This code should do it:

```
private String firstName = "myFName";

private String secondName = "mySName";

public void print(String fName , String sName){

System.out.println(fName);
System.out.println(sName);

}
```

you can also use System.out.print if you want them on the same line.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the question. Although I don't think the question is very clear.